# Maven DiffTypes with Liquibase changelog

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, command-line, liquibase

I am executing the below command

```
java -jar liquibase.jar
 --driver=<driver name>
 --clasapth=<classpath + liquibase jar>
 --changeLogFile=<file name + path>
 --url=<schema1>
 --username=<username>
 --password=<pwd>
 --referenceUrl=<schema2>
 --referenceUsername=<username>
 --referencePassword=<pwd>
 --diffTypes=data
generateChangeLog
```

**what i am expecting** : I am running the above command to extarct the difference in data(each table)  as a changeSet

The above command is not working as expected, Can anyone correct me with the right command.

Comment: When asking a question that involves the software reporting an error, it is extremely helpful to include the error message with the report. Any problem report should have three things - what you did, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hope so i have given you the details which will be helpful Steve. Expecting the benifitable answer asap.

Comment: When using the liquibase maven plugin, I don't think you can specify options on the command line. I think that the diffTypes option must be specified as an attribute in your POM. I don't personally use the liquibase maven plugin, so I am not 100% sure on that.